# Why are messages delivered to an address that doesn't exist?

Tags: postfix

here are the headers from a message I received recently:

```
Return-Path: <docusign@colodoors.com>
X-Original-To: sales@arix.com
Delivered-To: sales@arix.com
Received: by mail.arix.com (Postfix, from userid 1005)
    id 4G4B044ygFz5y8l; Tue, 15 Jun 2021 07:43:48 -0700 (PDT)
Received: from colodoors.com (unknown [118.39.98.71])
    by mail.arix.com (Postfix) with SMTP id 4G49zp2HXbz5vYk
    for <sales@arix.com>; Tue, 15 Jun 2021 14:43:34 +0000 (UTC)
Date: Tue, 15 Jun 2021 23:44:41 +0900
From: "DocuSign Electronic Signature and Invoice" <doteq@colodoors.com>
Message-ID: <3342.1.7.1.846776601@colodoors.com>
To: sales@arix.com
List-Unsubscribe: <https://colodoors.com/unsubscribe?redirect=rte3iS>, <mailto:postmaster@colodoors.com?subject=unsubscribe-66>
Subject: You got notification from DocuSign Electronic Signature Service 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternatve; boundary="_444_8"
```

now my question: there is no "sales" user account on the host that receives mail, and no such definition in the `/etc/postfix/virtual` either

how did this message get delivered to me? and how can I prevent messages written to anything@arix.com from getting delivered?

Comment: Please provide your postfix configuration

Comment: you mean the contents of my `main.cf`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton that's what I'm asking in the OP

Answer (score 1):

found the problem.  my system (Fedora) kindly defines in `/etc/aliases` a number of presumably helpful addresses:

```
info:          postmaster
marketing:     postmaster
sales:         postmaster
support:       postmaster
```

remove those definitions and no more mails to "sales"

Comment: This is *quite* unusual, and very much not a default on any known Linux distribution. Either someone or something configured those aliases.